# Firebase Passwordless Auth showing site not found page upon click link

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I'm extremely new to `react-native` and `firebase`, and I'm trying to setup `Passwordless Auth`.

The code I have written yet:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, TextInput, Button} from 'react-native';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: '',
      emailSent: false,
    };
  }

  setEmail = async email => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('emailLink', `${email}`);
    } catch (e) {
      // save error
    }

    console.log('Email is set');
  };

  getEmail = async () => {
    try {
      var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('emailLink');
    } catch (e) {
      // read error
    }

    console.log('Got email: ', value);
  };

  sendEmailLink() {
    var actionCodeSettings = {
      // The URL to redirect to for sign-in completion. This is also the deep
      // link for mobile redirects. The domain (www.example.com) for this URL
      // must be whitelisted in the Firebase Console.
      url: 'https://passless.page.link/85EH',
      iOS: {
        bundleId: 'org.reactjs.native.example.passless',
      },
      android: {
        packageName: 'com.passless_auth',
        installApp: true,
        minimumVersion: '12',
      },
      // This must be true.
      handleCodeInApp: true,
    };
    auth()
      .sendSignInLinkToEmail(`${this.state.email}`, actionCodeSettings)
      .then(() => console.log('email is sent'))
      .then(() => this.setEmail(`${this.state.email}`))
      .catch(err => console.log('error sending email', err));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="email"
          onChangeText={email => this.setState({email: email})}
        />
        <Button title="SignUp/LogIn" onPress={() => this.sendEmailLink()} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I am receiving the email successfully but the link doesn't work.

This is the error I get,
[image]

The link from the email opens in the browser instead of the app. How should I fix this??

I think I have setup the links in the console correctly, but I'm not sure about my code.

How do I progress further??
Help would be very much appreciated.

P.S I'm using `react-native-firebase v6`

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/e7v4ao

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you change the redirect URL from the default one to some other redirect URL that is not registered with your project on GCP.

Make sure you have the redirect URL whitelisted on your firebase project's credentials section on GCP oAuth consent.

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent

Make sure have whitelisted your redirect URL in there.

I hope this helps. Let me know if you get an issue.

Comment: My domain is listed under Authorized domains in the firebase console.
Why is it different from the GCP domains? Afterall firebase and GCP are quite well connected and organized

Comment: Although, I tried to whitelist my url from the link you have provided but its not accepting the link, I add the link but when I refresh the page, the link disappears from the console.